# Syntax problem with converting html code to a php variable which also includes Javascript

Tags: php

I have this line of code which works well, but I want to convert into a PHP variable:

`<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:freezModel('view_assumptions.php?id=<?php echo $adminArr['id'];?>&act=freez')" >`

I have tried this:

`$unlock='<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:freezModel("view_assumptions.php?id='.$adminArr["id"].'&act=freez")" class="actionIcons unlocked"></a>';`

I thought it was an escaping issue so I added the back slashes before the second ":

`$unlock='<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:freezModel(\"view_assumptions.php?id='.$adminArr["id"].'&act=freez\")" class="actionIcons unlocked"></a>';`

But still no luck. Why does this not work???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use ' instead of " for freezModel(), and scape it:

```
$unlock = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:freezModel(\'view_assumptions.php?id='.$adminArr["id"].'&act=freez\');" class="actionIcons unlocked"></a>';
```

Using " you are closing your onclick property.

Answer (score 1):

Your situation will be better handled using heredoc.

Try this instead:

```php
<?php
$unlock = <<<EOS
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="javascript:freezModel('view_assumptions.php?id={$adminArr['id']}&act=freez')" >
EOS;
```